# Screen Recorder for Ubuntu

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, screen-recording

I'm looking for free (gratis) software for Ubuntu that allows me to easily record the screen. I don't exactly have the best computer ever so I'm also looking for low ram consumption. Recording of audio is not required, I just need video.

Requirements:

- Must be gratis
- Must work for Ubuntu 12.04
- Would be cool if it had Unity integration
- Output of video format is not of matter to me
- (If possible) low system resource usage (RAM, processor usage and such)
- Keyboard short cuts to start and stop recording
- Would be great if it had a pause function
- I do not require any editing features, or audio recording (including system sounds)

*For new versions of Ubuntu please check [Screen recorder for Ubuntu 18.04 (Wayland)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/screen-recorder-for-ubuntu-18-04-wayland)*

Answer (score 5):

I've used [GTK RecordMyDesktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gtk-recordmydesktop/) before and was pleased with the result (but note that I have used only once for really simple stuff).

- [X] Must be gratis
- [X] Must work for Ubuntu 12.04
- [?] Would be cool if it had Unity integration *
- [X] Output of video format is not of matter to me **
- [X] (If possible) low system resource usage (RAM, processor usage and such) ***
- [X] Keyboard short cuts to start and stop recording ****
- [X] Would be great if it had a pause function
- [X] I do not require any editing features, or audio recording (including system sounds)

* What you mean by *Unity integration*? I remember that it did had an (interactive) tray icon.

** I don't remember exactly which filetype(s) it supports, but it's worth mentioning that I found it to be very limited (it's *.ogg* only IIRC).

*** I'm not able to say precisely about the resource usage, but I remember that I didn't notice any hiccups.

**** [It appears that there is](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/app_a.php).

Comment: This is better than other software I tried before, but in my windowed recording flickers every 3 or so seconds and I can see my Desktop (only in the finished .ogv, not while recording it)

Comment: Solution was to disable OpenGL Flipping in the Nvidia Control Panel (due to me using the proprietary Nvidia driver), which e.g. SimpleScreenRecorder recommends when you start it.

Comment: Also, my audio got HORRIBLY desynced from my video when recording (by a factor of about 0,7) which I can probably change in settings but there should be better defaults if it's really that