# Screen recorder for Ubuntu 18.04 (Wayland)

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, screen-recording

Ubuntu 18.04 uses Wayland, which gtk-recordmydesktop [does not support](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1336094#c4) (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_pixel'`). I ried pressing [Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/684ecd/screencasting_tool_for_wayland/) it freezed my computer and I had to hard-reboot it after 5 minutes.

How to record my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?

- Gratis, ideally open source.
- Outputs video in a format that YouTube can digest, if possible without needing intermediate conversions.
- Shows my mouse, and ideally shows when I click.
- Ability to select a particular area of the screen.
- Ideally with a small GUI or shortcut to easily stop the video.
- Bonus if it can record desktop sounds, and the microphone.

For past versions of Ubuntu please check [Screen Recorder for Ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/screen-recorder-for-ubuntu)

Comment: VLC can grab/transcode your desktop ...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek#how-can-i-improve-the-quality-of-recorded-gif-files) and [key-mon](https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon).

Install them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install peek key-mon
```

Then start them:

```
key-mon --visible_click
peek
```

Select the area you want to record.

key-mon shows the key presses and clicks, while peek records the video.

- The GUI is rather unintrusive and allow for easy selection of the area to record.
- Free and open source.
- Can record as WebM.
- Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 as of February 2018.
- No sound it seems.